# C ulong array operation CRC32

Tags: arrays, c, crc, operation, crc32

i'm really rusty when it comes with C and i need to understand code made by another developer, based around CRC32.
I've got a ulong array

```
static const ulong crc32_table[256] =
{
      0x00000000ul, 0x04c11db7ul, 0x09823b6eul, 0x0d4326d9ul,
      0x130476dcul, 0x17c56b6bul, 0x1a864db2ul, 0x1e475005ul,
      0x2608edb8ul, 0x22c9f00ful, 0x2f8ad6d6ul, 0x2b4bcb61ul,
      0x350c9b64ul, 0x31cd86d3ul, 0x3c8ea00aul, 0x384fbdbdul,
      ...
};
```

This array is then used in ciphering data, this way:

```
void CRC32(const byte *buf, uint len, const byte init[4], byte crc[4]) {
    memcpy(crc, init, 4);
    while (len--) {
        const byte * tmp = (const byte *)(crc32_table + (crc[3] ^ *buf));
        crc[3] = crc[2] ^ tmp[3];
        crc[2] = crc[1] ^ tmp[2];
        crc[1] = crc[0] ^ tmp[1];
        crc[0] = tmp[0];
        ++buf;
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is the line :

```
const byte * tmp = (const byte *)(crc32_table + (crc[3] ^ *buf));
```

It seems the whole array is used in addition and casted to byte (uint in fact) but i'm not used
to this kind of operation.

Can someone help me?

I need to write an equivalent to the CRC32 function but in C#
Would this work:

```
            uint[] crc = sharedkey;
            uint[] buff = new uint[] { 0x4fu, 0xaeu, 0x07u, 0x0bu, 0x68u, 0x56u, 0x34u, 0x12u };

            for(int i=0; i < len; i++)
            {
                byte[] tmp = BitConverter.GetBytes(crc32_table[(int)(crc[3] ^ buff[i])]);            

                crc[3] = crc[2] ^ tmp[3];
                crc[2] = crc[1] ^ tmp[2];
                crc[1] = crc[0] ^ tmp[1];
                crc[0] = tmp[0];
            }
```

Comment: "cipher, noun: a secret or disguised way of writing; a code. verb: put (a message) into secret writing; encode." - A CRC isn't a cipher, it's just an error detection code.

Comment: In my case it is used in a bluetooth communication between a device and a tablet, to secure it (somehow). A parameter is "ciphered" with CRC32 and must match between peripheral and controller. It's not my design

Comment: Quoting Schneier from Applied Cryptography: _"LFSRs are competent pseudo-random-sequence generators all by themselves, but they have some annoying nonrandom properties. Sequential bits are linear, which makes them useless for encryption."_ Though I'm not sure if what you're saying is more like trying "authentication" of sorts, but yeah, they probably shouldn't be using CRCs/LFSRs for that.

Comment: Yep! As i said, it's not my design, and i must work with it nevertheless... It's some kind of authentification, you're right, not really encryption

Comment: `ulong, uint` are not a standard types.  Please post their definitions.

Comment: @momone50 a CRC is an integrity check, not encryption nor authentication. Given a message (ie: `const byte *buf`) and a CRC (ie: `byte crc[4]`) you can determine if the original message has been altered by recomputing the CRC.

Comment: I agree... but as i said, i have to work with it... At the first, the designer of this bluetooth design was using AES encryption, but switched to CRC for code size reason... You think he should really reconsider it?

Comment: @momone50 well it depends on your goals. To start with, this isn't exactly a standard CRC, but it certainly isn't encrypting anything. If your goal is confidentiality (prevent unauthorized users from understanding a message) you need encryption and this will not suffice. If your goal is integrity (detect when a message has been altered from its original form) then a CRC or hash should work. We can't make assumptions about your business needs, nor assume liability for advice. I think you and your organization need to discuss your security concerns and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the lights again. I will mark my question as answered, as there are sufficient info here.

Comment: @h0r53, what makes you say that's not a standard CRC? It looks like one to me, and that constant `0x04c11db7` happens to match one of the common 32-bit CRCs.

Comment: @momone50, and, btw, the way to mark a question as answered is to use one of the checkmarks next to the answers, to pick that answer as "accepted". That makes the question marked as answered also in lists of search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect the entire function. The function is declared as follows:

```
void CRC32(const byte *buf, uint len, const byte init[4], byte crc[4])
```

`const byte *buf` - The input buffer that the CRC is being calculated for

`uint len` - The length of the CRC to be calculated

`const byte init[4]` - The initialization vector of the CRC

`byte crc[4]` - The output / result of the CRC calculation

We first see that `crc` is initialized to the initialization vector in `memcpy(crc, init, 4);` Then we have a loop that iterates `len` times. At the end of this loop, the `buf` pointer is incremented with `++buf`.

Now to the part you are having difficulty understanding.

Each byte of `buf` is XOR'd with `crc[3]`, the result of which is used as an offset into the `crc32_table`. The resulting value is stored in `tmp` which is then used to scramble the four bytes of `crc`. Key factors behind this working involve `crc32_table` having 256 entries, and there being 256 possible values of a byte (which is the result of the operation you are trying to understand). Thus the offset index is always valid.

The remaining operations are simply XORs that further scramble `crc`.

**UPDATE**

Although I've dissected the function, the primary confusion involves a concept known as pointer arithmetic. In C, the value of an unindexed  array (such as `crc32_table`) is a pointer to a memory location storing data of consecutive types, based on the array type and length. For example,

Let's say we have the following array `ulong crc32_table[256]` at memory location `0x400000`.

Then the value of `crc32_table` is `0x400000`.

Furthermore, `&crc32_table[0]` is also `0x400000` (this translates to *the address of the first entry in the crc32_table array*).

However, `&crc32_table[1]` is `0x400008` (if sizeof(ulong) is 8 bytes on your system)

Here is the interesting part.

`crc32_table + 1` is also `0x400008`, (the same as `&crc32_table[1]`).

This is known as pointer arithmetic, and it is the same concept that is used in the CRC code you provided. That code is simply calculating an offset 0-255 into an array of size 256, so each possible offset is valid and translated into an appropriate array index.

Comment: HI, first, let me thank you for answering at speed of light! I understand most part of it, and what you wrote confirms i was understanding right. 
It's the offset from crc32_table i don't undestand. It's a syntax i don't get. I'm used to C# and Java. C is far behind me

Comment: `crc32_table` is an array. In C arrays are technically pointers to memory the size of a type and the length of the array. For example, `ulong crc32_table[256]` stores a ulong and has 256 entries, so `crc32_table` is a pointer to `sizeof(ulong)*256` bytes. Pointer arithmetic involves adding to a pointer to acquire an offset to what could be an array entry. So basically, what you've found is a valid way to offset into an array, based on the base array pointer location. Does that help?

Comment: Seems i'm rusty with pointers to! I think i have all the answers in your post, but i need a little time to put it all together. I'll mark as answered if no further questions. But maybe you'll here from me again.

Comment: By what magic tmp (a byte?) becomes an array, as we can see tmp[3], tmp[2], etc...

Comment: `(const byte *)` is the final cast. If you notice, it's technically a pointer to one of the values of `crc32_table`. Let's say it happens to be `crc32_table[1]`. Then you could think of it as `const byte tmp[4] = 0x04c11db7`. Even though the pointer points to the first element of the crc32_table entry, there are technically 4 bytes at that location, and you can simply access them just as you would an array of size 4.

Comment: It's the same thing as casting a byte array of size 4 to a `byte *`, since arrays are technically pointers. You can't really cast anything to an array explicitly though, so you cast to a pointer instead, and understanding the pointer is to an array of size 4 you must not try to access elements beyond indices 0-3.

Comment: I updated my question, as i need to write an equivalent in C#. Could you take a look please?

Comment: @momone50 Asking a question for clarification on the original code you provided is a bit different than asking a question about how to recreate in C#. IMHO it should be created as a new question, since the original question was about pointer arithmetic in C.

Comment: you are right. Not really used to stack overflow. Sorry

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes there are subtle differences but as the confusion was regarding pointer arithmetic the point here was to show that the value of an unindexed C array is the same as the address of the same array at element 0.

Comment: Updated to provide clarity and avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
const byte * tmp = (const byte *)(crc32_table + (crc[3] ^ *buf));
```

with `buf` pointing to the next byte of the input, this xors the next input byte with the high byte of the current CRC value, and looks that up in the table.
Or rather, it looks up the address to that element in the table, and casts it to a `const byte *`, so that the bytes can be read later. (`crc32_table + (foo)` is the same as `&crc32_table[foo]`.)

Then, this:

```
crc[3] = crc[2] ^ tmp[3];
crc[2] = crc[1] ^ tmp[2];
crc[1] = crc[0] ^ tmp[1];
crc[0] = tmp[0];
```

shifts the value of the CRC by 8 bits (note the indexes), and xors in the value picked from the table. Here, `tmp` is a pointer-to-byte (probably `unsigned char *`), which then points to the first byte of one of the values in the table. The accesses through `tmp[0]` to `tmp[3]` then read that byte and the following bytes of the value, individually. If `ulong` is `unsigned long`, it's at least 32 bits, or four bytes, so the accesses don't go to the following value. The byte order needs to be known to be correct for that to work, though.

I would do that using `uint32_t`s, instead of char arrays, but whatever. Something like this, that is, though I didn't test, it's probably wrong:

```
uint32_t tmp, crc = init;
while (len--) { 
    tmp = crc32_table(((crc >> 24) & 0xff) ^ *buf++);
    crc = (crc << 8) ^ tmp; 
}
```

Using that precalculated table is an optimization for calculating CRCs. If you look at the definitions, you'll usually see them as circuits where a single bit is shifted out from one end of a register, used to possibly flip some of the bits in the register, and an input bit shifted in at the same time. The table lookup just deals with that 8 bits at a time; the values in the table are the net bits flipped in the register when those 8 bits get shifted out.

Answer (score 0):

I mark this question as answered, as there are enough informations here to solve my problem

Comment: I understand you are new here, so no worries learning the ropes. What you provided here is more of a comment than an answer. Proper answers should be beneficial to others that may have similar issues in the future. Think of StackOverflow as an encyclopedia for programming related questions. I'm not telling you what to do, but in my opinion you should delete this answer and mark another answer of your liking as the solution. I hope the responses here are helpful.